# select with a null value

Tags: angularjs, null, html-select, ng-options

Is it possible to render correctly a select, with a few options which one value is null?

I will provide a simple example:

```
$scope.value = null;
$scope.list = [{ id: null, description: "none"},
    { id:1, description: "one" },
    { id:2, description: "two" },
    { id:3, description: "three" }];
```

html:

```
<select ng-model="value" ng-options="item.id as item.description for item in list">
</select>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ECQ3XUnv75sJW4Ix8IyO

After rendering everything is ok (none is selected), but when I click into select there is one additional option - empty (and while `$scope.value` is `null` the "empty" options remains). When I choose other option and while `$scope.value` is not `null` everything seems to work. Is there some kind a way to remove the empty option that browser generates while model is `null`?

This behaviour is the same on Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to add meaningless null-options manually. You just need to add empty `option` into HTML:

```
<select ng-model="value" ng-options="item.id as item.description for item in list">
    <option value="">none</option>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.list = [
    { id:1, description: "one" },
    { id:2, description: "two" },
    { id:3, description: "three" }
];
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/8j9NUT3rUfwUj4QJhZqa?p=preview

Comment: Also worth mentioning that this is explained in the docs also

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work using `undefined` instead of `null`, and removing the `id` property of your default value :

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.value = undefined;
    $scope.list = [{ description: "none"},
        { id:1, description: "one" },
        { id:2, description: "two" },
        { id:3, description: "three" }]

});
```